# How can I use a Global Key in more than one widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I tried to show my popupitems when I put my cursor over my Popupbutton and I made it by using Global key. But the problem is that i tried to do the same thing to my other popupbuttons but when I did this, everything went wrong. The error was that I can not use a global key for more than one widget. Below You can see my global key that I'm using and my widgets. So if you have any idea how to fix this, please let me know here.

```
GlobalKey popUpButtonKey = GlobalKey();

  openPopUpItem() {
    GestureDetector? detector;
    searchForGestureDetector(BuildContext element) {
      element.visitChildElements((element) {
        if (element.widget != null && element.widget is GestureDetector) {
          detector = element.widget as GestureDetector;
        } else {
          searchForGestureDetector(element);
        }
      });
    }

    searchForGestureDetector(popUpButtonKey.currentContext!);

    detector!.onTap!();
  }


body: ListView(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 80,
                width: 185,
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo2.png'),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              if (!Responsive.isMobile(context))
                PopupMenuButton(
                    tooltip: '',
                    child: Text(
                      'Escorts',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 24,
                        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                      ),
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry>[]),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
              if (!Responsive.isMobile(context))
                InkWell(
                  onHover: (value) {
                    if (value) openPopUpItem();
                  },
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: PopupMenuButton(
                      key: popUpButtonKey2,
                      tooltip: '',
                      color: Color(0xFF262533),
                      position: PopupMenuPosition.under,
                      child: Text(
                        'Agenturen & Clubs',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 24,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        ),
                      ),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry>[
                            const PopupMenuItem(
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  'Escortagenturen',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const PopupMenuItem(
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  'Bordelle',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const PopupMenuItem(
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  'Laufhauser',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const PopupMenuItem(
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  'Saunaclubs',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const PopupMenuItem(
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  'Domina & BDSM-Studios',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const PopupMenuItem(
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  'Tantra & Massaage-Studios',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]),
                ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
              if (!Responsive.isMobile(context))
                PopupMenuButton(
                    tooltip: '',
                    child: Text(
                      'Inserieren',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 24,
                        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                      ),
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry>[]),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
              if (!Responsive.isMobile(context))
                InkWell(
                  onHover: (value) {
                    if (value) openPopUpItem();
                  },
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: PopupMenuButton(
                      key: popUpButtonKey,
                      tooltip: '',
                      color: Color(0xFF262533),
                      position: PopupMenuPosition.under,
                      child: Text(
                        'Werben',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 24,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        ),
                      ),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry>[
                            const PopupMenuItem(
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  'Werbenformate',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const PopupMenuItem(
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  'Preise',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try adding an argument to `openPopUpItem`, like this:

```
openPopUpItem(Key widgetKey) { //added argument
    GestureDetector? detector;
    searchForGestureDetector(BuildContext element) {
      element.visitChildElements((element) {
        if (element.widget != null && element.widget is GestureDetector) {
          detector = element.widget as GestureDetector;
        } else {
          searchForGestureDetector(element);
        }
      });
    }

    searchForGestureDetector(widgetKey.currentContext!); //changed to use the key passed, not an hardcoded one

    detector!.onTap!();
  }
```

Comment: please can you show me an example based on my code to be more understandable @il_boga

Comment: If you replace your `openPopUpItem` code with the one I posted, your IDE should warn you automatically of various errors, because each `openPopUpItem` invocation will lack an argument. So you just have to add to each invocation the corresponding key for the widget you want to "tap" and make the pop up appear

Comment: But here it says the getter "currentContext" isnt defined for the type 'key' @il_boga

Comment: My bad, change from `openPopUpItem(Key widgetKey)` to `openPopUpItem(GlobalKey widgetKey)`

Comment: It still doesn't works. Inside my widgets i have called openpupitems as a function and i have to put something inside brackets (GlobalKey widgetKey). When i put this it doesnt works. Is there a way to declare this inside my widgets. Please look at my code as for reference @il_boga